# Android detect sms belongs to sender or receiver

Tags: android, cursor, sms

I want to detect from sms list, which of messages are mine and witch of them  belongs to other contacts.

For example:

Me: "body": Hi John

John "body: Hi there...

```
  Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                //detect here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.CREATOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html) field to get the creator. Compare this to your address (mobile number) to distinguish yourself from the other people. You can get your number with the following:

```
(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getLine1Number();
```